# why the "open" command runs under the home directory?

Tags: macos, bash

Under Mac OSX (Mountain Lion), I have a shell script "a":

```
#!/bin/bash
open -a Terminal b
```

which run another shell script "b" using Terminal:

```
echo `pwd`
```

Something interesting is that, no matter where my running scripts are located, the `pwd` command in "b" always returns the home directory.

Questions:

1. Why does this happen?
2. How to set the running environment to be the working instead home directory (ie, return the working directory when arriving at `pwd`)

Comment: Sorry, don't you think your question is more appropriate for unix.stackexchange.com?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a Bash script tell what directory it's stored in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will probably work in `b`:

```
echo $( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )
```

Answer (score 1):

I am a ubuntu Linux user but I'm pretty sure the cli is very similar for both. Anyways, I believe the default directory when you open a new terminal window is your home directory. Unless you change it within your settings. This is the likely reason for the pwd command in "b" printing your home directory.